# How to add a label to a gtkmm statusicon object?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I am writing a simple application in gtkmm that displays a status icon in the task bar. I'd like to have a label widget appear when the mouse hovers over the icon but am having no luck finding an example. How would one go about doing such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean you are using `Gtk::StatusIcon` which has a function of `set_tooltip_text()`. See: [Gtkmm StatusIcon](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1StatusIcon.html#ac55a8196e4a9626b96a8abb77ea5730a) for more details.